# Output to a file a command with pipe

Tags: powershell, logging, output

I'm trying to output to the file commands which removes files and starting service but no chance.

```
get-childitem -path $cleanpath -recurse | remove-item -force -Recurse >> $log
Start-Service -Name "Bamboo" >> $log
```

I have tried something like this but also it failed:

```
get-childitem -path $cleanpath -recurse | remove-item -force -Recurse | Tee-Object -FilePath $log -Append
Start-Service -Name "Bamboo" | Tee-Object -FilePath $log -Append
```

I have tried to run powershell script with following ways:
`.\clean-cache-folder.ps1 *>&1 output1.txt` and `.\clean-cache-folder.ps1 | Out-file .\output1.txt` and `.\clean-cache-folder.ps1 >> .\output1.txt`

All these methods failed. Log file is empty. Please help.

Another approach which give an empty log file

```
try
{
Write-Output "===============================" >> $log
Get-Date -Format G >> $log
Remove-Item -Path $cleanpath -force -Recurse | Out-File $log -Append
#Start-Service -Name "Bamboo" >> $log
}
catch 
{
#Write-Warning $Error[0] >> $log
#Write-host ($_ | Tee-Object -FilePath $log -Append)
Write-Output ($_) >> $log
}
```

Comment: Don't get the question. The logfile is empty or it is not creating?

Comment: Sorry. Log file is empty.

Comment: Ok, it will be empty, because `Remove-Item -Force -Recurse` don't provide any output :)

Comment: Thx. You are right but in my case when deleted files/folders are in use it will generate an errors. Errors are visible (when you run the script is PowerShell command line) and should be treated as a 'output' and it should be possible to somehow log it into the file.

Comment: Ok, so you need to catch the exception in the output file then.

Comment: I have tried that also but there was nothing in log. See above example